# Update multiple identical dbs at the same time

Tags: sql-server, update, sql-server-2022, multi-server-admin

We have a software package where the db are running sql 2022.

I have many regions. Subdomains for each company that we work with.  However the software and dbs are identical in structure.

Is there a way that if I update 1 regions db I can update the other 20 simultaneously?

Or is there a management software that can do this?

Comment: What kind of updates do you mean? Schema, data, or both? If data, you want the data to always be in sync between all of them?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you can do this, the two methods I've used regularly on-prem are:

Building a [Central Management Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group?view=sql-server-ver16).
From here you can connect to multiple instances at the same time, they do have to be reachable from the CMS server, and execute whatever script you want on all of them at the same time. Even if you're not using this as an upgrade tool, if you're managing a bunch of instances, this will help you a lot for day-to-day work.

Another more complex, but possibly better solution would be to use a [Visual Studio Database project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/creating-and-managing-databases-and-data-tier-applications-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).
Inside of this project you can import a database/scripts, or develop your own scripts which you can deploy on 1 or multiple servers.

The CMS is by far the easiest and quickest to start using, however, the project might have serious benefits for you in the long run since it runs a bunch of extra checks making it easier to deploy without manually having the check everything.
All depends on how complex your scripts are or what you're really expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing that and any multi server queries and sql commands through powershell, and I am learning more and more and I am very thankful for my current team that has set me up in that direction.

I am going to post a powershell script here
but there are a few considerations that you need to be aware before you try it:

1. google `Invoke-DbaQuery` and see more about it
2. permissions to run powershell in other servers
3. this is not meant to give you a full answer today, but to set you in your way towards it

```
Clear-Host
$DestinationServerList = "server1,server2,server3"
$SQLQuery = "select * from dbo.users where name = @name"


#$DestinationServerList | Format-Table

foreach ($DestinationServer in $DestinationServerList) {

    $ConDestinationServer = $null
    try{
        $ConDestinationServer = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance $DestinationServer -SqlCredential $SQLAdmin -TrustServerCertificate
    }
    catch {
        #$errorMsg = "$(Get-Date) - Could not connect to " + $DestinationServer  + "."
        Write-Host -foregroundcolor Red $errorMsg        
    }

      
  if ($null -ne $ConDestinationServer) {

      Write-Host -foregroundcolor Blue "SUCESSFULLY CONNECTED TO  "$ConDestinationServer.Name" AS "$ConDestinationServer.ConnectedAs""
      

        try {

            
            Write-Host "Connecting to: " $DestinationServer 
            #--------------------------------------------------------------------

            $SQLQueryResults = Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $ConDestinationServer   -Query $SQLQuery #-SqlParameters @{ Name = "Maria" }
            
            #$SQLQueryResults | Format-Table
        
            #Write-Host -foregroundcolor DarkGreen "WRITING RESULTS TO: $ReportingInstance ON DATABASE: $ReportingDatabase - $(Get-Date)`n"
            #Write-DbaDbTableData -SqlInstance $ReportingConn   -Database $ReportingDatabase -InputObject $SQLQueryResults -Table dbo.tblTheJobSchedules_ -AutoCreateTable
            
            #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        }
        catch {
            #Write-Host $DestinationServer " error"
            $errorMsg = "$(Get-Date) - Could not connect to " + $DestinationServer  + "."
            Write-Host -foregroundcolor Red $errorMsg        
        }

        Write-Host -foregroundcolor Green "END - CONNECTED TO $SQLInstance - $(Get-Date)"

  }else{

      Write-Host -foregroundcolor Gray "SKIPPING - NOT CONNECTED TO  "$DestinationServer.Name" AS "$DestinationServer.ConnectedAs""

  }

    
}
```